# How can I generate a PBKDF2 password hash in python?

Tags: python, pbkdf2

I'm using some software that stores it's internal user database in a JSON file (users.json) where each user has a field called `password` where the values look like this:

```
pbkdf2:10000:f30dd5755d4d172d:e7b2fdda936b4ad5335c3b76c8f3568b0e3b14ce1d9b8ca1e32b7627545d0a3811aa3407a814731b1ee1c86e108c66c1616b1ea2570f7ecf8d04d4f465c33947
```

I want to modify this `users.json` programatically from python to reset a user password, without having to go through this application UI.

How can I generate a `pbkdf2:xxxxxx` string for a new password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

```
pbkdf2:10000:f30dd5755d4d172d:e7b2fdda936b4ad5335c3b76c8f3568b0e3b14ce1d9b8ca1e32b7627545d0a3811aa3407a814731b1ee1c86e108c66c1616b1ea2570f7ecf8d04d4f465c33947
```

follows the format

```
pbkdf2:iterations:saltinhexstring:hash64bytesinhexstring
```

to generate a new `pbkdf2:xxx` you can use [hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac) which is builtin  since Python 3.4.

For example the `pbkdf2:10000:f30dd5755d4d172d:e7b2fdda936b4ad5335c3b76c8f3568b0e3b14ce1d9b8ca1e32b7627545d0a3811aa3407a814731b1ee1c86e108c66c1616b1ea2570f7ecf8d04d4f465c33947` seems to be the hash of the password `admin` using `pbkdf2_hmac('sha1',...)`

You can generate the hash for password `admin` and salt `f30dd5755d4d172d` over `10000` iterations like this:

```
from hashlib import pbkdf2_hmac
iterations = 10000
salt = bytes.fromhex('f30dd5755d4d172d')
passwordtohash = 'admin'
hash = pbkdf2_hmac('sha1',bytes(passwordtohash,'utf-8'), salt, iterations, dklen=64)
print(f"pbkdf2:{iterations}:{salt.hex()}:{hash.hex()}")
# pbkdf2:10000:f30dd5755d4d172d:e7b2fdda936b4ad5335c3b76c8f3568b0e3b14ce1d9b8ca1e32b7627545d0a3811aa3407a814731b1ee1c86e108c66c1616b1ea2570f7ecf8d04d4f465c33947
```

Or in general for a completely new password (with a new random salt):

```
from hashlib import pbkdf2_hmac
import os
import random
import string
iterations = 10000
salt = os.urandom(8)
passwordtohash = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(16))
hash = pbkdf2_hmac('sha1',bytes(passwordtohash,'utf-8'), salt, iterations, dklen=64)
print(f"New password: '{passwordtohash}'")
print(f"pbkdf2:{iterations}:{salt.hex()}:{hash.hex()}")

New password: 'LGVDFKSBEUISDGUM'
pbkdf2:10000:0ef9f6feb244efc1:2e61922d793aca79f5ad326033987d8714779795cc26e99fae2f44014afac4efdbe17e543379afd1d578a16ee3f4476dc4112cf047c908868ed0318cdf248d64
```